# google cloud apache server overwrite

Tags: apache-2.2, google-cloud-platform

I'm fairly new at using Google Cloud hosting and I recently learned how to create a VM instance with an apache server. I found a tutorial that showed how to overwrite the server's default web page with a blank page that says "Hello World", but I want to overwrite it with my website's index page, which is in a storage bucket. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can [mount your Bucket in a directory](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) on your VM using Cloud storage Fuse or use [RSYNC](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) to synchronize a your bucket or with a VM local folder.

But if you objective is mount static web pages you can upload a [static webpage to a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).